# Concave and convex shape div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working with concave and convex shapes of div. I want a concave shape and on mouse hover then it turns to convex. Can anyone point me in the right direction? So far this is the sample code I have tried below is the image

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 120px;
}
.inner:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px; 
  content: '';
  right: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  top: 100%;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.inner:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  top: auto;
}

.inner:hover:after {
 height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You can use `:before` and ':after' to achieve that functionality. `:before` almost the same like ':after', only difference `top` position.

```css
.card {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: tomato;
}
.section {
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0 0;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 120px;
}
.inner:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px; 
  content: '';
  right: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  top: -150px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.inner:hover:after {
 top: -120px;
}

.inner:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px; 
  content: '';
  right: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  top: 130px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.inner:hover:before {
 top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can play with it to achieve better hover response and transition speed.

Comment: here I tried to add elastic type effect but it is not coming you have any idea how should I add this effect.

Comment: Try to understand a code how it works, then apply it. It's irrelevent to this question.